# how to start timer on a specific time in android

Tags: android, timer, handler

I have a question. I want to start the timer on a specific time. i.e., I have a time say, 05:10:02. then the timer shall start from 05:10:02.
Eg, 05:10:02, 05:10:03, 05:10:04 and so on.

when I open the activity, it should fetch the current time and the timer shall start the described above in the question.

I have the following code.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    inputString = str;  //05:10:02


    try {
        date = sdf.parse(inputString);

        Log.i("Test", "in milliseconds: " + date.getTime());  
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(mStartTimeGlobal== 0L) {
        mStartTimeGlobal = date.getTime();
        mHandlerGlobal.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTaskGlobal); 
        mHandlerGlobal.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTaskGlobal, 100);
    }



     private Runnable mUpdateTimeTaskGlobal = new Runnable(){

    public void run() {

        //DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.####");

        final long start = mStartTimeGlobal;
        long millis = date.getTime();

        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
           int minutes = seconds / 60;
           seconds = seconds % 60;
           int hours = seconds/3600;

           String timer = String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds);

           ///mTotalTimeTakenGlobal = timer;

           txt_start_timer.setText(timer);                                                                         
           mHandlerGlobal.postDelayed(this, 200);               

     }    
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html):

```
Date date = new Date("...")
Timer t = new Timer(); 
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
   public void run() {
     // do your actions
   }
}, date);
```

Your task will be launched in non GUI thread so use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to update you interface after the time event occurs. The limitation of this approach is that your program must be running in order to get the notification, it will not start automatically at the given time. You can schedule multiple tasks on the same timer so they could start at different dates.

Comment: No I don't want to start the timer on specific dates. I just want when I open the activity, it should fetch the current time and the timer shall start the described above in the question.

Comment: You can start the timer at any time before the scheduled date. The timer will start the scheduled TimerTask at the scheduled time.